# syslog question

Tags: linux, unix, logging, syslog

I am looking into syslog.
I understand that it is a centralized logging facility that collects logs from various sources.
I have heard that syslog can generate alerts on conditions e.g. max file size of log file is reached.
Is this true?
Because I haven't found how this is done.
Most posts just refer to the logging.
How is the event generation done?
I.e. if I have an app that acts as a log source (redirects logging to a syslog) then is it possible my app can receive an alert, if the max file size has been reached?
How is this configured?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the application perspective, the [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) function is primarily a receiver of information from the application; the application can write messages to the syslog.  There are various bits of information that the application provides to the syslog daemon, including the severity of the message.

The [syslog daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd) can be configured to take different actions on receipt of different types of message.

No, your application cannot receive an alert when the maximum file size is reached - at least, not via syslog.  You might get a SIGXFSZ signal which you can trap.  You might prefer to look at your resource limits and keep tabs on your file size to avoid the problem.

Comment: My application is a running in a different machine altogether.So when for example the wiki says: `It also provides devices which would otherwise be unable to communicate a means to notify administrators of problems or performance` what does it mean when it says notify administrators?

Comment: It means that if you have a device driver in the kernel managing a device, that device driver can arrange to send messages via syslog to the administrator when otherwise the device would have no reliable method to convey complex information - it could return an error number, but that's essentially all.